# Smiley icons stored in database using API not displayed properly

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I have created a PHP API which stores data in database sent from iPhone/iPad/iPod. Users are sending smiley icons inside the data but on PHP page there is only `???` displayed.

Comment: because the font( Unicode ) you are using don't have these smiley meaning

Comment: What should i do to show all data in php same as it shown in Iphone / iPod etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue few months ago.

You need to set the encoding of your DB to `utf8mb4_general_ci`

It's very important to encode as well your DB connector to `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Answer (score -1):

step 1: take the value of the emoticon, in this case it would be some unicode which will be saved in the database.

step 2: store the smiley icon image in the folder, and link it to your php code.

step 3: use a if condition as to decide if the unicode equal to smiley unicode if yes then, display the smiley icon which is stored in the folder.

ex:   if([databse smiley unicode]==='U+1F60A[should contain the unicode value]')
        {
           ***display the stored smiley icon***
        }